# Search array values

Tags: php

Hi every I am having the follwing array. I need to all the values based on `Id` values. How can i do this.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [Description] => Get first Description
        [Code] => GF
        [Value] => 1.0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 3
        [Description] => Get second Description
        [Code] => GF
        [Value] => 1.0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 4
        [Description] => Get third Description
        [Code] => GF
        [Value] => 1.0
    )
```

Comment: Exactly what you want to do ? You want some function to search through those arrays?

Comment: The above array is from my database table. Now i need to customize it (i.e) If i need only the description and value of `Id` 3 how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'Id' => '1',
        'Description' => 'Get first Description',
        'Code' => 'GF',
        'Value' => 'Test 1'
    ),
    array(
        'Id' => '2',
        'Description' => 'Get second Description',
        'Code' => 'GF',
        'Value' => 'Test 2'
    ),
    array(
        'Id' => '3',
        'Description' => 'Get third  Description',
        'Code' => 'GF',
        'Value' => 'Test 3'
    )
);

function getArrayValue( $array , $id )
{
    foreach( $array as $a )
    {
        if( $a['Id'] == $id )
        {
            return $a;
        }
    }
    return 'U/N';
}

print_r( getArrayValue( $array , '2' ) );
```

Comment: instead of using global variable put the array as 2nd parameter.

Comment: @DeiForm Noting different, but edited :)

Comment: well... I made asnwer same as yours 'cos I saw you are returning only 1 value but seems you made it same as I did :D

Comment: @DeiForm no, in first edit fixed it :D

Comment: Ye haven't seen gonna delete my answer then :)

Comment: I am trying this for searching multiple id that is for `2` and `3`

Comment: @RelicSet and what is output ? both of 2 and 3 must rerurned ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
foreach($my_arr as $arr) {
   $new_arr[$arr['ID']] = $arr['Value'];
}
print_r($new_arr);
```